# Tidy approach to regression models, ideally with dplyr

Tags: r, regression, dplyr, lm

Reading the documentation for `do()` in dplyr, I've been impressed by the ability to create regression models for groups of data and was wondering whether it would be possible to replicate it using different independent variables rather than groups of data.

So far I've tried

```
require(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

models <- data.frame(var = c("cyl", "hp", "wt"))

models <- models %>% do(mod = lm(mpg ~ as.name(var), data = mtcars))
Error in as.vector(x, "symbol") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'symbol'

models <- models %>% do(mod = lm(substitute(mpg ~ i, as.name(.$var)), data = mtcars))
Error in substitute(mpg ~ i, as.name(.$var)) : 
  invalid environment specified
```

The desired final output would be something like

```
  var slope standard_error_slope
1 cyl -2.87                 0.32
2  hp -0.07                 0.01
3  wt -5.34                 0.56
```

I'm aware that something similar is possible [using a lapply approach](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/looping_strings.htm), but find the apply family largely inscrutable. Is there a dplyr solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't pure "dplyr", but rather, "dplyr" + "tidyr" + "data.table". Still, I think it should be pretty easily readable.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>%
  gather(var, val, cyl:carb) %>%
  as.data.table %>%
  .[, as.list(summary(lm(mpg ~ val))$coefficients[2, 1:2]), by = var]
#      var    Estimate  Std. Error
#  1:  cyl -2.87579014 0.322408883
#  2: disp -0.04121512 0.004711833
#  3:   hp -0.06822828 0.010119304
#  4: drat  7.67823260 1.506705108
#  5:   wt -5.34447157 0.559101045
#  6: qsec  1.41212484 0.559210130
#  7:   vs  7.94047619 1.632370025
#  8:   am  7.24493927 1.764421632
#  9: gear  3.92333333 1.308130699
# 10: carb -2.05571870 0.568545640
```

If you really just wanted a few variables, start with a vector, not a `data.frame`.

```
models <- c("cyl", "hp", "wt")

mtcars %>%
  select_(.dots = c("mpg", models)) %>%
  gather(var, val, -mpg) %>%
  as.data.table %>%
  .[, as.list(summary(lm(mpg ~ val))$coefficients[2, 1:2]), by = var]
#    var    Estimate Std. Error
# 1: cyl -2.87579014  0.3224089
# 2:  hp -0.06822828  0.0101193
# 3:  wt -5.34447157  0.5591010
```

Comment: Also have a look at the package `broom` with a nice vignette http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing particularly complicated about the approach in the linked page. The use of `substitute` and `as.name` is a bit arcane, but that's easily rectified.

```
varlist <- names(mtcars)[-1]
models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
    form <- formula(paste("mpg ~", x))
    lm(form, data=mtcars)
})
```

dplyr is not the be-all and end-all of R programming. I'd suggest getting familiar with the *apply functions as they'll be of use in many situations where dplyr doesn't work.

Comment: Spot on on the `dplyr` reference.